# Java: Difference between new Properties(...) and new Properties().putAll(...)

Tags: java, dictionary, constructor, properties

What's the difference between

```
    final Properties properties = new Properties(System.getProperties());
```

and

```
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.putAll(System.getProperties());
```

I've seen this change as a [fix commit in JBoss AS](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/commit/8c4864b8ebbb689694c4fb128bd6fb44a6ce9a46).

Comment: Which snippet is the 'fixed' code?

Comment: The second one. Added a link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example which demonstrates the difference:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties defaults = new Properties();
        defaults.setProperty("x", "x-default");

        Properties withDefaults = new Properties(defaults);
        withDefaults.setProperty("x", "x-new");
        withDefaults.remove("x");
        // Prints x-default
        System.out.println(withDefaults.getProperty("x"));

        Properties withCopy = new Properties();
        withCopy.putAll(defaults);
        withCopy.setProperty("x", "x-new");
        withCopy.remove("x");
        // Prints null
        System.out.println(withCopy.getProperty("x"));
    }
}
```

In the first case, we're adding a new non-default value for the "x" property and then removing it; when we ask for "x" the implementation will spot that it's not present, and consult the defaults instead.

In the second case, we're copying the defaults into the property with no indication that they *are* defaults - they're just values for properties. We're then replacing the value for "x", then removing it. When as ask for "x" the implementation will spot that it's not present, but it doesn't have any default to consult, so the return value is null.

Answer (score 2):

The first sets the given properties as defaults; the second sets them as non-default values.

Comment: The second is not recommended. From the doc: "Because Properties inherits from Hashtable, the put and putAll methods can be applied to a Properties object. Their use is strongly discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or values are not Strings."

Answer (score 0):

There's one more thing: `putAll()` will *not* copy default values.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Properties defaults = new Properties();
  defaults.setProperty("x", "x-default");

  Properties withDefaults = new Properties(defaults);
  // Prints x-default
  System.out.println(withDefaults.getProperty("x"));

  Properties withCopy = new Properties();
  withCopy.putAll(withDefaults);
  // Prints null
  System.out.println(withCopy.getProperty("x"))
}
```